# Sharepoint calendar items - Automatic Permissions possible? (WSS 3.0)

Tags: sharepoint, calendar

Within sharepoint you can set permissions on a calendar basis, and on a per-item basis.

Essentially, there are 2 kinds of calendar items we have, both with different permissions. We'd like to simplify the permissions setting process, ideally so its automatic.

Is it possible to have the per-calendar-item permissions set automatically, based on (for example) a custom checkbox column?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, no. BUT you can write an event handler, listening to `ItemAdded` event and `ItemUpdated` event which performs `BreakRoleInheritance()` and sets the required permissions. However, bear in mind that the results may be "interesting" if a user who added the item, does not have access to it after the event handler has performed its work (the user saw the item, then he/she refreshed the page and sees an error page).